# High-level Serialisation Frameworks for Persistent Data Structures

Tags: python, c++, serialization, binary, protocol-buffers

I need to serialise some structured data for an in-memory index. In particular, I need to make persistent a large array (gigabytes) of heterogeneous structs made up of primitive data types (`int`s, `float`s, `char`s), that needs to be parsed by C++ and Python programs on the same machine. This array will be static, I do not need to update any of its structs.

I found some frameworks like [Protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), but I am not sure whether they are the right tools for this job because much of the other questions here or tutorials on the Internet about Protocol buffers focus on message exchange and RPC. My primary requirement is fast reads/writes of files of gigabytes of binary-encoded data.

My question is: should I consider other frameworks for this kind of problem?

Comment: The question is a little bit opinion-based. Anyway protobuf for sure is a good tool to serialize big amount of data. How will you transmit that data later on (whole 1GB structure at a time, small chunks, whatever) is another question.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is leave Protobuf and try Flatbuffers or Cap'N Proto they don't serialize the data and are built for the case of primitive data.